# Rotate a diamond tiling

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid, tiling

Any regular hexagon can be tiled with diamonds, for instance like so (stolen from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50562/25180)):

```
   ______
  /_/_/\_\
 /_/\_\/\_\
/\_\/_/\/_/\
\/_/\_\/_/\/
 \_\/_/\_\/
  \_\_\/_/
```

We'll consider the above a tiling of size 1 (since the diamonds' sides are made of one / or \ each). The same tiling of size 2 would look like:

```
      ____________
     /   /   /\   \
    /___/___/  \___\
   /   /\   \  /\   \
  /___/  \___\/  \___\
 /\   \  /   /\  /   /\
/  \___\/___/  \/___/  \
\  /   /\   \  /   /\  /
 \/___/  \___\/___/  \/
  \   \  /   /\   \  /
   \___\/___/  \___\/
    \   \   \  /   /
     \___\___\/___/
```

Your task is to rotate diamond tilings by a multiple of 60 degrees. The diamond tiling in the input can be in any size (and the size is not explicitly specified in the input). But it would always be a valid tiling, and all sides of the hexagon would have the same length.

These are the above examples rotated by 60 degrees clockwise:

```
   ______
  /_/\_\_\
 /\_\/_/\_\
/\/_/\_\/_/\
\/\_\/_/_/\/
 \/_/\_\_\/
  \_\/_/_/

      ____________
     /   /\   \   \
    /___/  \___\___\
   /\   \  /   /\   \
  /  \___\/___/  \___\
 /\  /   /\   \  /   /\
/  \/___/  \___\/___/  \
\  /\   \  /   /   /\  /
 \/  \___\/___/___/  \/
  \  /   /\   \   \  /
   \/___/  \___\___\/
    \   \  /   /   /
     \___\/___/___/
```

The input is a non-negative integer and a diamond tiling. Your program (or function) should rotate it by the integer * 60 degrees. You decide whether to rotate clockwise or counterclockwise, as long as it is consistent. Both the input and output shouldn't have extra leading or trailing spaces.

This is code-golf. Shortest code wins.

Related questions:

- [Rotate a Chinese checkerboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51964/25180)
- [Rotate a two-dimensional list by 45 degrees](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26541/25180)
- [Scale up a Diamond Tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50562/25180)

Comment: Martin will be so jealous!

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>452</s> <s>356</s> 315 bytes

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Edit: Saved 96 bytes by realising that my algorithm doesn't need to know the number and size of diamonds separately, plus a few minor golfs that I missed the first time around. Saved 41 bytes by rearranging the code so that the destination was always the same pair of characters, plus a minor golf that I missed when converting to my previous algorithm.

```js
r=
(s,n)=>(z=s.search`_`,l=(f,n=z*2+1)=>[...Array(n)].map(f),a=s.split`\n`,l(_=>(o=a.map(s=>[...s].fill` `),l((_,r)=>l((_,c)=>(d=z+c*2-r,a[s=z+r-c]&&(a[s][r+c]=='/'?o[r][d]=o[r][d+1]='_':0,a[s][r+c-1]=='\\'?o[r][d]='/':0),a[--s]&&(a[s][r+c]==`_`||a[s][r+c-1]==`_`?o[r][d+1]=`\\`:0)))),a=o.map(a=>a.join``)),n),a.join`\n`)
;
```

```html
<pre id=i1>
   ______
  /_/_/\_\
 /_/\_\/\_\
/\_\/_/\/_/\
\/_/\_\/_/\/
 \_\/_/\_\/
  \_\_\/_/
</pre>
<input type=button value="Rotate!" onclick="i1.textContent = r(i1.textContent, 1)">
<pre id=i2>
      ____________
     /   /   /\   \
    /___/___/  \___\
   /   /\   \  /\   \
  /___/  \___\/  \___\
 /\   \  /   /\  /   /\
/  \___\/___/  \/___/  \
\  /   /\   \  /   /\  /
 \/___/  \___\/___/  \/
  \   \  /   /\   \  /
   \___\/___/  \___\/
    \   \   \  /   /
     \___\___\/___/
</pre>
<input type=button value="Rotate!" onclick="i2.textContent = r(i2.textContent, 1)">
```

Explanation: Considers each pair of output characters, which could be `__`, `/_`, `_\`, `/` or `\`, checking for the appropriate characters in the input which map to those output characters. Ungolfed:

```js
function rotate(str, num) {
  // Measure the size using the indent of the _ in the first row.
  var size = str.indexOf('_');
  var arr = str.split('\n');
  while (num--) {
    // We build a character array to represent the output by turning the
    // input into a nested array and replacing everything with spaces.
    // Note that the output will have any trailing spaces from the input.
    var res = arr.map(s => Array.from(s).fill(' '));
    // Loop over a diamond that encloses the hexagon.
    for (var destrow = 0; destrow <= size * 2; destrow++) {
      for (var col = 0; col <= size * 2; col++) {
        var destcol = size + col * 2 - destrow;
        var srcrow = size + destrow - col;
        var srccol = destrow + col;
        // Map / to __, \ to / and __ to \.
        // We write __ first in case it gets overwritten by / or \.
        if (arr[srcrow]) {
          if (arr[srcrow][srccol] == '/') {
            res[destrow][destcol] = res[destrow][destcol + 1] = '_';
          }
          if (arr[srcrow][srccol - 1] == '\\') {
            res[destrow][destcol] = '/';
          }
        }
        // Need to check both positions in case one was overwritten.
        if (arr[srcrow - 1] &&
            (arr[srcrow - 1][srccol] == '_' || arr[srcrow - 1][srccol - 1] == '_')) {
          res[destrow][destcol + 1] = '\\';
        }
      }
    }
    arr = res.map(a => a.join(''));
  }
  return arr.join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 81 bytes

```
ju.es.e.reh|@s.e.e[yYykZ)bGCa+LV,t-y+k*3Y*5J-+kY/lG2Jc2j406610 4K"_/\\_\\"dKbGQ.z
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ju.es.e.reh%7C%40s.e.e%5ByYykZ%29bGCa%2BLV%2Ct-y%2Bk%2a3Y%2a5J-%2BkY%2FlG2Jc2j406610+4K%22_%2F%5C%5C_%5C%5C%22dKbGQ.z&input=5%0A++++++____________%0A+++++%2F+++%2F+++%2F%5C+++%5C%0A++++%2F___%2F___%2F++%5C___%5C%0A+++%2F+++%2F%5C+++%5C++%2F%5C+++%5C%0A++%2F___%2F++%5C___%5C%2F++%5C___%5C%0A+%2F%5C+++%5C++%2F+++%2F%5C++%2F+++%2F%5C%0A%2F++%5C___%5C%2F___%2F++%5C%2F___%2F++%5C%0A%5C++%2F+++%2F%5C+++%5C++%2F+++%2F%5C++%2F%0A+%5C%2F___%2F++%5C___%5C%2F___%2F++%5C%2F%0A++%5C+++%5C++%2F+++%2F%5C+++%5C++%2F%0A+++%5C___%5C%2F___%2F++%5C___%5C%2F%0A++++%5C+++%5C+++%5C++%2F+++%2F%0A+++++%5C___%5C___%5C%2F___%2F)

Rotates counterclockwise.

Each 60° rotation is performed using the following algorithm.  Suppose the input is a hexagon of order *k*, so it has 2⋅*k* + 1 rows and 4⋅*k* columns.  To find the rotated character at row *i* column *j*, let

- *u* = *i* + *j* − *k*
- *v* = *j* − 3⋅*i* + 5⋅*k*

Then the output character is

- `\`, if the input has `/` at row (*u* + 1)/2 column (*v* + 1)/2; else
- `/`, if the input has `_` at row *u*/2 column *v*/2 or row *u*/2 column (*v* + 2)/2; else
- `_`, if the input has `\` at row (*u* + 2)/2 column *v*/2 or row (*u* + 1)/2 column (*v* − 1)/2; else
- space.

(We do not count characters at half-integer indices.)

Comment: I think you can guarantee which positions have `\ `s, it's just the `_`s that you have to check in both places.

Comment: @Neil Yes, you know where the `\ `s are, but you might have to draw two `_`s for each `\ `.

Comment: Oh, you check each underscore separately?