# Shrink ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The inverse of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/232957/enlarge-ascii-art-mark-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Your challenge is to, given a piece of ASCII art generated by the above question  and its enlargement factor, shrink it down to its original size.

### The enlargement process

[Or look at this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/232957/enlarge-ascii-art-mark-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1)

ASCII art within a limited character set can be enlarged to a certain (odd) size by replacing certain characters with larger versions of themselves, like so:

```
-\
 |
_/
, 3 =>

   \
--- \ 
     \
    |
    |
    |
     /
    /
___/
```

Because each character is enlarged to a 3x3 square.

Only those six characters (`\/|-_` ) can be enlarged, and only those will be in your input. For a more detailed explanation, see the linked challenge.

I/O may be as a char matrix, ascii art, list of rows, etc.

### Testcases

```
\
 \
  \
, 3 =>
\


         
---------
         
, 3 =>
---


 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | , 3 =>
|
|
|


 | \       / | 
 |  \     /  | 
 |   \___/   | 
 |           | 
 |           | 
 |           | 
   \       /   
    \     /    
     \___/     
, 3 =>
|\_/|
|   |
 \_/ 


_______________
\             /
 \           / 
  \         /  
  /         \  
 /           \ 
/             \
\             /
 \           / 
  \_________/  , 3 => 
_____
\   /
/   \
\___/               
               

        /\        
       /  \       
      /    \      
     /      \     
    /        \    
   /          \   
  /            \  
 /              \ 
/  ____________  \
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
     /      \     
    /        \    
___/  ______  \___, 3 => 
  /\  
 /  \ 
/____\
  ||  
  ||  
_/__\_


\        /
 \      / 
  \    /  
   \  /   
    \/    
\        /
 \      / 
  \    /  
   \  /   
    \/    , 5 =>
\/
\/


      /             /
     /             / 
    /             /  
   /   -------   /   
  /             /    
 /             /     
/             /      
\             \      
 \             \     
  \             \    
   \   -------   \   
    \             \  
     \             \ 
      \             \, 7 => 
/-/
\-\
```

Comment: It would be interesting if you had to auto-detect the enlargement factor (choosing the maximum).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
»/⁹ÐƤ⁺€
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lines that yields a list of lines.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qbv1HjTsPTzi25FHjrkdNa/4/3L3l8PLI//8VoEA/BsbigokoKMSgCumDiBhkIX0IJwYhpA8zJgYmBBeBiHGhiIDFuFBFQGJcQJF4JAAUg7mrBoxQnEpTIYJ@BDoP7lqgGJD8bwwA)**

#### How?

```
»/⁹ÐƤ⁺€ - Link: list of lists of characters, Lines; pixel size, N
   ÐƤ   - for non-overlapping infixes
  ⁹     - ...of length: chain's right argument, N
 /      - ...yield: reduce by:
        -             maximum (vectorises)
                      (Note: space is less than any other character used)
      € - for each:
     ⁺  -   repeat the last link - i.e. do Ṁ⁹ÐƤ
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

```
x=>n=>x.replace(/.+\n.+\n.+/g,y=>[...(z=y.split`
`)[~-n/2]].map((w,i)=>i%3-1?"":w<"!"?z[n-1][i]:w).join``)
```

Now actually works!

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Rickrolling jokes are mostly fine in chat, but bringing them over to main is just clutter.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
{.@-.&' '@,;.3~2 2&$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVNNS8NAEL3Pr3iINA00O5IiQkIhIHjy5NWBPYitePEHKP3rMZvsZ7KhxYNDF/Jed4Z5O28@@xtVHHFoUGCHOzTDqRQeX56f@m/VVWpToOh2rdqfa9Sb276k06F5f/v46rZtezyXtMcJr63SNbZjeklCGH7Dyf0JF1S5iLhsxg8unpU8sXXZ3rMEw2GI1nqAHru4BiOqjxGH@hb7@ivadBokiIMJMcGmpkTQYPZYDObovoA4qSfX1PfN8No83HWfS6EjSSkOj2Ip9s06iiMBE8WxhpnKnFCvNX5LjCa0w/Kz@xfqosbpdX2fZvIl3S8XaTmo4IFp/OY7uG8y3p/ShgYeVkbNc9NkyJnMyKAjaTc9rMri5nKmdm1yJGZG9g7L0cnSJD6TpDNJlzhxW44m5Ggq@18)

With `(y x,:h w) u;.3 a` we can split `a` into tiles of size `h w` while sliding the window by `y x`. Because we don't want overlapping tiles, we can simply build a 2x2 matrix of the input, e.g. `3 3,:3 3`. On these tiles `u` gets applied, which flattens `,` the tile into a list, removes any whitespace `-.&' '` and then reduces the tile to the first remaining element `{.`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＮθＷＳ⊞υ⭆⪪ιθ⌈κＥ⪪υθ⭆⌈ι⌈Ｅι§νμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tc@xCoMwEADQPV9x4wUiGTo6dXSwCF0DxVqpodGqTVqH/nsao6kKXXuEkDzujruiyvvinitrk6Y1@mDqc9ljR2PyqqQqAT0fdS@bK1IKmXlUaBhMkuYtHlslNUoGHWWQ5oOsTY03Sl2LzOVoXJLMlLTUhnS5Kh3dddvrpLmUAzYMauojtnZHYA4uwisQBxBb4uMl1sSnj1iIhzYi0FcmIxvxRrYyGnFyWoWzMNfbn82of6VfO0Y@5h3deOsd3ZfY6Kk@) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the enlargement factor followed by a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the enlargement factor.

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⭆⪪ιθ⌈κ
```

Input the strings, but split them into substrings of length equal to the enlargement factor and take the maximum character of each substring.

```
Ｅ⪪υθ⭆⌈ι⌈Ｅι§νμ
```

Split the list of strings into sublists of length equal to the enlargement factor, then transpose the sublists and take the maximum character of each, joined back into a string, and print each sublist's string on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 84 bytes

```javascript
a=>n=>a.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>(d=b[i/n|0]||=[])[x=j/n|0]=d[x]?.trim()||c),b=[])&&b
```

```js
f=
a=>n=>a.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>(d=b[i/n|0]||=[])[x=j/n|0]=d[x]?.trim()||c),b=[])&&b

str2mat = str => str.split('\n').map(r => [...r]);
mat2str = mat => mat.map(r => r.join('')).join('\n');
test = (s, n) => console.log(mat2str(f(str2mat(s.slice(1, -1)))(n)));

test(String.raw`
\
 \
  \
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
---------
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 | 
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
 | \       / | 
 |  \     /  | 
 |   \___/   | 
 |           | 
 |           | 
 |           | 
   \       /   
    \     /    
     \___/     
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
_______________
\             /
 \           / 
  \         /  
  /         \  
 /           \ 
/             \
\             /
 \           / 
  \_________/  
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
        /\        
       /  \       
      /    \      
     /      \     
    /        \    
   /          \   
  /            \  
 /              \ 
/  ____________  \
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
       |  |       
     /      \     
    /        \    
___/  ______  \___
`, 3);

test(String.raw`
\        /
 \      / 
  \    /  
   \  /   
    \/    
\        /
 \      / 
  \    /  
   \  /   
    \/    
`, 5);

test(String.raw`
      /             /
     /             / 
    /             /  
   /   -------   /   
  /             /    
 /             /     
/             /      
\             \      
 \             \     
  \             \    
   \   -------   \   
    \             \  
     \             \ 
      \             \
`, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
f n|let g[]=[];g x=maximum(take n x):g(drop n x)=g.map g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcaxDsIgFEbhnaf4B4c6AIObhidpG3JTKZLCtWlpwtB3R2X2LN950b64GGudwWd0Gb4fTT8@PIpJVEI6UpdpcWCU6913z@29tjdeJVrha6LAJnB2G035cnAM7HY146baVQADIKSUXwV@DY0Tf4BuaAhrrQY@)